# How can I change the size of an individual pin?

Tags: craft3, plugin-smartmap

I tried this code, but getting 'unexpected token errors". Probably something to do using incorrect syntax.

```js
{% js %}
    var markerId = 'smartmap-mapcanvas-1.{{ entry.id }}.addressInformation';
    smartMap.marker[markerId].setOptions({
        'icon':       '{{ icon }}'; 
        'scaledSize:' 'new google.maps.Size(32,32)'
    });
{% endjs %}
```

The error in the console

```js
var markerId = 'smartmap-mapcanvas-1.550.addressInformation';
smartMap.marker[markerId].setOptions({
    'icon':       '//d1ado4imyxw3fk.cloudfront.net/html/pin-otto-12.png'; 
    'scaledSize:' 'new google.maps.Size(32,32)'
})
```

Comment: Did you made mistakes while copy pasting? Because your syntax doesn't seem correct unless smartmap is using `eval` but even so using `;` after object properties is wrong

Comment: The above is the smart map code as described in the smartmap docu under: Different icons for different marker types. I did make a mistake though with the ; character. After replacing the ; for a , the map reloads without errors. However the icons are still not sized.

Comment: They don't state to do `'new google.maps.Size(32,32)'` because that will pass a string... I can't think of a reason why smartmap expects a string rather than the actual object.

Comment: it should be: 
'scaledSize': new google.maps.Size(32,32)

(wrong postion of the colon, value is not a string)

Comment: @RobinSchambach Smart Map is actually smart enough to recognize strings that contain `google.maps`, and parse them correctly. :)

Comment: Oh, but that would be in Twig... he's using JS here. In that case, you are correct about passing the object directly!

Comment: This thread is a little old but I found it helpful in solving this same issue. @LindseyD hit on the solution. Pass the object directly instead of as a string.
In other words remove the quote marks like this:
'scaledSize': new google.maps.Size(32,32)
 
Works for me!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there are a couple of notable errors in your JS:

- You have a semi-colon at the end of your `icon` line. That should be a comma.
- On the `scaledSize` line, you have the colon *inside* the quote. That should be outside.
- *Added per Robin's comment...* Since you're doing this in JS (not Twig), the `new google.maps.Size(32,32)` shouldn't be enclosed in quotes. Pass in the JS object directly.

Try something like this...

```js
{% js %}
    var markerId = 'smartmap-mapcanvas-1.{{ entry.id }}.addressInformation';
    smartMap.marker[markerId].setOptions({
        'icon':       '{{ icon }}',
        'scaledSize': new google.maps.Size(32,32)
    });
{% endjs %}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You already stated the wrong ;

Aside from that, i managed to change the size in one of my projects, where i had to use a bitmap image, this way:

```
marker[id] = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: region.pos,
    map: map,
    icon: {url: imageMarker,
            size: new google.maps.Size(52, 52),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 35) // offset
            }
});
```

I didn't use the smartmaps-plugin, but i think that's irelevant.

(The png had a different size, that's the reason `size` and `scaledSize` have different values)

Comment: Tried as suggested. Code seems to be OK, no errors. But unfortunately still no sizing